# Wget downloading old version of file

Tags: linux, bash, script, download, wget

I'm trying to create an auto-updater script. I have a script that will continually download files from a Nexus repository. If the file in the repository is updated, the script will continue to download an OLD version of the file that was at the link.

Here is the script I made:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    echo "Re-Downloading needed plugins from Nexus..."
    wget -O PGM-1.0-shaded.jar http://maven.spiromarshes.com/service/local/repositories/ApexGames/content/com/apexgames/PGM/1.0/PGM-1.0-shaded.jar
    wget -O Lobby-1.0-shaded.jar http://maven.spiromarshes.com/service/local/repositories/ApexGames/content/com/apexgames/Lobby/1.0/Lobby-1.0-shaded.jar
    sleep 10
done
```

The files download fine, but aren't the "updated" versions. If I push an update to the repository and download it manually (Using the same link I pass into the `wget` command) it will be the updated file while the one downloaded with the script is an old version

I've tried stopping the script, deleting the files, deploying a new update to nexus, and starting the script again and it will STILL somehow be downloading older versions. I've also tried with `--no-dns-cache` as well as `--no-cache`.

Same thing happens with `curl -O <link>`.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the web app, not wget.

Comment: Really? I didn't think that would be an issue if downloading with a browser from the same link would result in the new version of the file

Comment: It may be hitting a different server behind a balancer, one that hasn't updated yet. Hence, web app.

Comment: It's my own server. There's no possibility of it hitting a different server.

Comment: what about adding ?version=somerandomnumberhere  to the end of the URL to try and bypass URL caching etc ?

Comment: Okay, yeah, that seems to work. The only major issue with that is it has to be changed each time it's re-downloaded. I'm trying to make a "set it and forget it" type of a thing. I'm not super fluent when it comes to scripting, is there any way to change the "somerandomnumberhere" every time it loops through?

Comment: Played with it a bit more. It only works when I start and stop the script changing the random number each time. if I use $RANDOM, it won't work properly.

Comment: Is there a proxy server? wget has --no-proxy option too.